# How to add a lambda layer for subtracting different values from different axes

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras

I have two CNNs cascaded and after the first CNN I want to do some post process on the output before giving to second CNN. I was trying to add a lambda layer in between with the following function:

```
def pre_pro_layer(x):
    x=x*255.0
    x[..., 0] -= 103.939
    x[..., 1] -= 116.779
    x[..., 2] -= 123.68
    return x
```

Basically these are images and i am scaling up and then subtracting some constants corresponding to R,G,B channels.

But it is showing the following error

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I think i cant do such operations in a tensor. Please help if there is a way around. I am new to Keras.

Comment: Since this is not an operation in the graph I would do this outside tensorflow with numpy. If you want to do this with tf, your operatin has to support gradients and this is not trivial.

Comment: mult_layer = Lambda(lambda x: x * 255.0)(layer). like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a constant value but using tensor operations only:

```
def pre_pro_layer(x):
  x = x*255.0 # this is fine
  tosub = K.constant([103.939, 116.779, 123.68])
  # repeat or tile tosub based on the shape of x, depends on what you have
  # ...
  return x - tosub # element wise subtraction
```

Note that subtraction does support [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting) so you don't have to get exactly the same shape as `x` but something that would broadcast to the shape of `x` when subtracting.